# read csv data as integer in python

Tags: python, csv

I have an`csv` file with the data in the following format

`1,F,1,10,48067
2,M,56,16,70072
3,M,25,15,55117
4,M,45,7,02460
5,M,25,20,55455
6,F,50,9,55117
7,M,35,1,06810
8,M,25,12,11413
9,M,25,17,61614`

now i want to read each line and store one row in a list and also convert M to 1 and F to 0. How can this be done in python

Something like

> temp = [1,0,25,17,2414]

Comment: How are you reading things now?

Comment: Or how are you doing anything? What have you tried? Are you getting an error? Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import csv

result = list()
with open('filepath.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        result.append(list())
        for item in row:
            if item == 'F'
                result[-1].append(0)
            elif item == 'M':
                result[-1].append(1)
            else:
                result[-1].append(item)
```

Here is a shorter and a beautiful solution:

```
import csv

result = list()
with open('filepath.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        result.append([i if (i!='F' and i!='M') else (0 if i=='F' else 1) for i in row])
```

Note that I didn't test the code. I just blindly wrote it here directly.