# python importing csv file without appostrof signs

Tags: python

I'm importing a clean csv-file, yet when I import it to python it shows up as ['1','3',...]

How can I get rid of the ' '. They don't appear in the csv. file

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your code and what you see? I'll help you. Pls post actual output so its clearer.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523842/read-csv-data-as-integer-in-python

Comment: `row = [int(x) for x in row]` for each row containing integers...

Answer (score 1):

CSV (`in.csv`):

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Python:

```
import csv

with open("in.csv") as c:
    reader = csv.reader(c)
    for row in reader:
        print([int(s) for s in row])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python reads all values from your file as strings. So you need to cast any value (if they are all integers) to int like so:

```
v = int(value_that_you_read)
```